# is there a way to use string trim for this purpose

Tags: string, tcl, trim

I have a random expression like "a.a.b" I need to trim "a.b" from this expression. Is there any way to use "string trimright" for this purpose? (I want the first character "a").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a specific string when it is at the end, you don't use `string trimright` (it's second argument is really a *character set* and only happens to be written as a string). Instead, you should use a `regsub` or some code like this:

```
proc removeIfLast {mainString toRemove} {
    set r [string length $toRemove]
    if {$toRemove eq [string range $mainString end-[expr {$r-1}] end]} {
        return [string range $mainString 0 end-$r]
    }
    return $mainString
}
```

This will then do this (from an interactive session):

```
% removeIfLast "a.a.b" "a.b"
a.
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use `string trimright`. As man page says, `string trimright` removes *any* trailing character belonging to the second argument. Therefore, if you do

```
string trimright a.a.b a.b
```

it starts from the end of `a.a.b` and removes any of `a`, `.`, or `b`, leaving you with the empty string.

To perform what you need, you can use a regular expression with the `regsub` command:

```
regsub {a\.b$} a.a.b ""
```

gives you the right string

```
a.
```

The regular expression (first argument) says: take an `a` character, followed by a literal `.` character (escaped with the back slash, because `.` means *any* character), followed by a `b`, at the end of the string (`$`).

This way you are not limited to the `a` and `b` characters, but you can also make it more general:

```
regsub {.\..$} $string ""
```

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern of characters is always *"<something>*.*<something>...*" and all you want if the first *<something>,* you may be best off going with:

```
lindex [split $input .] 0
```

This will split the input on periods, and then give you the first element.